# Killer benefit of Reactive Extensions?

Tags: .net, javascript, functional-programming, system.reactive

What is the killer benefit of Reactive Extensions (for either .NET or JavaScript)? Why should a developer learn and use them?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Reactive Extensions gives developers a way to compose complex event processing and asynchronous computation across Observable collections using a much more functional and declarative syntax.

A fairly simple example can be found at:

[Mike Chaliy: Reactive Extensions AI: Domain Events Example](http://chaliy.name/archive/2010/1/business_logic_rx_example/)

The clincher for me, even on a simple example, is this:

> ...notify manager about all noticeable
>   transfers.

```
Account.TransferMoney
       .Where(_ => _.Amount > 100.0m)
       .Subscribe(_ => SendMessageToManager());
```

As you can see, subscribing using Rx clearly defines our intent in a clear and concise manor. You can imagine chaining together complex logic (much like a complex LINQ query) to make some very interesting functionality.

You might also want to take a look at:

[Reactive Framework (Rx) Wiki: (not yet) 101 Rx Samples](http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples)

Comment: While I agree that Reactive Exensions make the completion handler clear, I believe that the 'await' keyword in C# 5 will make it even clearer. Reactive Extensions are great at doing things like - "waiting for multiple async operations to complete".

Comment: 'Mike Chaliy: Reactive Extensions AI: Domain Events Example' Page has an eeror